# Универсальные библиотеки для реляционных баз данных

Tags: python, база-данных, поиск-библиотек

Существует библиотека `SQLAlchemy` позволяющая работать с различными реляционными базами данных через запросы (такими как MySQL, PostrgeSQL, SQLite, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server и др.)

Существуют ли аналоги данной библиотеки?

Comment: `peewee` что ли, что-то ещё было

Comment: Можно вбить "sqlalchemy analogs" в любой поисковик и получить результат. 
Еще ponyorm, pydal.